# What formula or method could I go to subtract amounts from values in a range using a table

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a master sheet with values of what I would sell for. I want to create a formula or rules where I can subtract commission based on the value of the cell. I want to be able to edit from the table only so I don't have to mess around with hundreds of cells formulas when things change. I also don't want to just take commission by percentage. I know how to link the cells. I want a formula that will look in the table and say hey its between the two values so ill extract this amount of commission. I have attached a picture of an example of the rules table.

I've tried doing `IF` statements and ran into too many arguments issues.

I expect the formula to look in my table and take out the proper commission beside it.

[image: Sample Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Main!B2-VLOOKUP(Main!B2, 
 {REGEXEXTRACT(Comission!$A$3:$A$13, "\d+")*1, Comission!$B$3:$B$13}, 2))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

you can do various things like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A9:A<>"", IF(COUNTIF(A9:A, A9:A)>1, 
 B9:B-(B9:B*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B9:B, 
 {{REGEXEXTRACT(A3, "\d+")*1, -B3%  };
  {REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "\d+")*1, -B4%};
  {REGEXEXTRACT(A5, "\d+")*1, -B5%};
  {REGEXEXTRACT(A6, "\d+")*1, -B6%};
  {400, 0}}, 2))), 
 B9:B-(B9:B*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B9:B, 
 {{REGEXEXTRACT(C3, "\d+")*1, -D3%  };
  {REGEXEXTRACT(C4, "\d+")*1, -D4%};
  {REGEXEXTRACT(C5, "\d+")*1, -D5%};
  {REGEXEXTRACT(C6, "\d+")*1, -D6%};
  {400, 0}}, 2)))), ))
```

[image: 0]

assuming Ema is a reseller and Jane & Yuki are one-timers

---

**alternatives: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Main!A2:B, 2, 0))-
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Main!A2:B, 2, 0)), 
 {IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(Comission!A3:A, "\d+")*1), Comission!B3:B}, 2)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This has got me going in the right direction. However im in a little confusion from my lack or experience with the Array formula.  I have separate sheets that get distributed to Re-seller clients and One time clients. The formulas on these pages will be manipulated so that it points to the pertaining customer type in the commissions sheet. I hope i am making sense :)

Comment: There's 4 sheets involved Main - This holds the value im being paid. Commission- Holds the table with both Re-seller and One timers values to subtract. Then (2 one for each client type) Distribution- This is that the clients will receive to look at their prices.

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A9:A<>"", B9:B-(B9:B*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B9:B, 
 {{REGEXEXTRACT(A3, "\d+")*1, -B3%  };
  {REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "\d+")*1, -B4%};
  {REGEXEXTRACT(A5, "\d+")*1, -B5%};
  {REGEXEXTRACT(A6, "\d+")*1, -B6%};
  {400, 0}}, 2))), ))` this is how you apply only purple rule set for prices in B9:B - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcvPh.png

Comment: I still think this wont work because i update one cell then it apply it to everything. The sheet is also a little complex i made a sample here that is editable. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QkZID-grlTPmSyeLqsz0VOZ0WTc_Uee32j8j0GkQb1Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to subtract it yes but i dont want to look up by item. I just care about subtracting commission based off what i will be paid which depends on the client type.

Comment: I added a formula that I got to work however I don't understand how to look up between the two numbers in the one cell. So right now it will only work if the exact value is there when it does VLookup.

Comment: change 0 to 1 in your VLOOKUP formulae

Comment: ii entered 1 but it still gets the error - did not find in the vlookup evaluation. This is the code `=(Main!B3)-VLOOKUP(Main!B3,(Comission!$C$3:$C$13):(Comission!$D$3:$D$13),2,1)` i updated it in the sheet also.